# Return an answer depending on which number is given (if statement)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create an *if* sentence and return the following values accordingly:

- If (0 - 40) - Return 1000
- If (40 - 80) - Return 970
- If 80+ - Return 900

I have tried:

```
=IF(R10<40,if(R40<10<80,970,900))
```

It only returns the values 1000 and 900. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your second IF should throw in an error... IF R40<10<80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was very close, you missed the part where you define what happens when the value is less than 40, this will do it :

```
=IF(R10<=40,1000,IF(R10<=80,970,900))
```

I change the < to <= you may not want this, but to me it makes sense to include.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
=IF(R10<40,1000,IF(R10<80,970,1000))
```